# Семантика html5, тег main

Tags: html5, семантика

Вопрос по HTML5 (семантика).

Есть тег *main*. Он размещён на главной странице новостного ресурса. В него входят превью новостей. По клику превью разворачивается страница детального просмотра новости (со своим *main*).

Правильно ли я поступаю, что превью новостей на главной странице заключены в main?

Я читал документацию, там говорится об уникальном, не повторяющемся контенте. Является ли превью, в таком смысле, не уникальным контентом?

P.S.: я не могу дать ссылку, потому как всё только на уровне начала вёрстки.

Comment: Тег <main> должен быть в единственном числе в пределах одной страницы.

Answer (score 4):

Ответ на первый вопрос: да, правильно. Давайте разберёмся: тег `main` - уникальное содержимое страницы, а

> Элементы не являющиеся контентом (из него исключаются) в aside

Ваше глобальное использование этого тега семантически верное. Проще запомнить: использовать его один раз.

Касательно, самих превью: в стандарте заложен тег `section` который допускает вложенность в себя собственные `h1`, `header`  и `footer`.  Рекомендую прересмотреть структуру тегов.

Не зная структуру вашего сайта, сложно ответить, но предположим, что помимо n-нного количества превью на главной, вы предположим разместите сквозной блок - ленту из топ-5 статей, сходных по контенту (первый абзац, краткое описание....)  - то такой вид контента считайте уже повторяющимся.

Ответ на второй вопрос: В понятие уникальность, поисковики закладывают исключительно единожды размещённый материал. Но при этом не накладывают штрафы за таковые превью, при размещении рядом ссылки (кнопки) ведущей на страницу с полным текстом документа.

Послесловие: несмотря на мою любовь к HTML5, применение его в production-проектах сопровождается с поддержкой <s>динозавра</s> всеми любимого Internet Explorer-а. Обратите на это внимание в процессе разработки.

Comment: Спасибо, очень развёрнутый ответ.
Единственное, что я прокомментирую момент с main. Вы правы, но не как body, Элементы не являющиеся контентом (из него исключаются) в aside. Т.е. в дерево он сидит глубже намного, причём произвольно в том месте, которое мы считаем главным контентом текущего документа.
На самом деле у меня тут 1ин вопрос был - про превью.  Спасибо.